# Trying to configure IMAP mail server with Alfresco for Outbound Emails. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I could really use some help here.

My company is starting an internal project and I was asked to dig a bit into Alfresco so we could have an ECM for that project. Problem is I have zero experience in this so obstacles come by very often.

I used the Google Click to Deploy feature for Alfresco and have been playing around a little following Alfresco's video tutorials. To test Alfresco's mail functionalities I created an IMAP mail server using Postfix and Dovecot and everything seems to be working fine when sending emails between users (I've been using mutt client).

The problem is... I seem to have configured everything I can find but Alfresco won't send any invitation email.

I've configured this in alfresco-global.properties:

```
### E-mail site invitation setting ###
notification.email.siteinvite=true

# Props following https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/IMAP-subsystem-props.html #
# ENABLING THE IMAP PROTOCOL #
imap.server.enabled=true
imap.server.port=143
imap.server.host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (External IP of Alfresco)

alfresco.protocol=http
alfresco.host=${localname}
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.context=alfresco

imap.config.home.store=${spaces.store}
imap.config.home.rootPath=/${spaces.company_home.childname}
imap.config.home.folderPath=cm:Imap Home

# ENABLING IMAPS #
imap.server.imaps.enabled=true
imap.server.impas.port=993
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456
```

I'm pretty sure I might be making some big mistakes here... I also tried using mail.username, mail.password, mail.from.default... Nothing worked...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco can be configured for inbound, outbound email delivery and additionally you can configure an IMAP protocol adapter to browse thru the node hierarchies using IMAP clients. You did the last which has nothing todo with outbound mails. You need to make you familiar with email protocol concepts before you start to configure something you don't understand.

To allow to *send* mails you need to configure the Outbound mail. e.g. :

```
#
# Outbound Email Configuration
#-------------
mail.host=localhost
mail.port=25
#mail.username=anonymous
#mail.password=
mail.encoding=UTF-8
mail.from.default=noreply@mycompany.com
mail.smtp.auth=false

mail.testmessage.send=false
mail.testmessage.to=
mail.testmessage.subject=Outbound SMTP
mail.testmessage.text=The Outbound SMTP email subsystem is working.
```

Please check Alfresco docs for  [Outbound SMTP configuration properties](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/email-outboundsmtp-props.html)

I would recommend to

- *not* use IMAP if you do not really need it since it is very expensive and buggy
- use a local mail deamon like exim, postfix to queue all outbound emails send by Alfresco since Alfresco will not retry if something goes wrong while sending an email.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a testmessage config in Alfresco-global.properties:

```
mail.testmessage.send=true
mail.testmessage.to=Your Mail address
mail.testmessage.subject=AlfOutbound Mail System
mail.testmessage.text=Sendung Mails Workshop
```

then Alfresco will send the testmessage on Startup and you can See errors (if any) in the Logs easier.